# How to use Index within a for loop from one method to another? flutter

Tags: arrays, flutter, for-loop, mobile, flutter-layout

I am trying to call the index i am utilizing within the init state results[] loop but every-time within  the speak() method, [i] is classified as undefined. I am able to hardcode values such as results[2] and that works in my app but I want to utilize the [i] so that all the text can be played one at a time per the results array. Please if you could help me achieve this.

```
void initState() {
    savedata();
    super.initState();

    tests = [
      widget.label00,
      widget.label0,
      widget.label1,
      widget.label2,
      widget.label3,
      widget.label4,
      widget.label5,
      widget.label6,
      widget.label7,
      widget.label8,
      widget.label9,
      widget.label10,
      widget.label11,
      widget.label12,
      widget.label13,
      widget.label14,
      widget.label15,
      widget.label16,
      widget.label17,
      widget.label18,
      widget.label19,
      widget.label20,
      widget.label21,
      widget.label22,
      widget.label23,
      widget.label24,
      widget.label25,
      widget.label26,
      widget.label27,
      widget.label28,
      widget.label29,
      widget.label30,
      widget.label31,
      widget.label32,
      widget.label33,
      widget.label34,
      widget.label35,
      widget.label36,
      widget.label37,
    ];

    results = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < tests.length; i++) {
      if (widget.label00 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label00);
        // tts.speak(widget.label00);
        // tts.setVolume(1.0);
      }
      if (widget.label0 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label0);
      }
      if (widget.label1 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label1);
      }
      if (widget.label2 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label2);
      }
      if (widget.label3 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label3);
      }
      if (widget.label4 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label4);
      }
      if (widget.label5 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label5);
      }
      if (widget.label6 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label6);
      }
      if (widget.label7 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label7);
      }
      if (widget.label8 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label8);
      }
      if (widget.label9 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label9);
      }
      if (widget.label10 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label10);
      }
      if (widget.label11 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label11);
      }
      if (widget.label12 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label12);
      }
      if (widget.label13 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label13);
      }
      if (widget.label14 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label14);
      }
      if (widget.label15 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label15);
      }
      if (widget.label16 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label16);
      }
      if (widget.label17 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label17);
      }
      if (widget.label18 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label18);
      }
      if (widget.label19 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label19);
      }
      if (widget.label20 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label20);
      }
      if (widget.label21 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label21);
      }
      if (widget.label22 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label22);
      }
      if (widget.label23 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label23);
      }
      if (widget.label24 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label24);
      }
      if (widget.label25 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label25);
      }

      if (widget.label26 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label26);
      }
      if (widget.label27 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label27);
      }
      if (widget.label28 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label28);
      }
      if (widget.label29 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label29);
      }
      if (widget.label30 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label30);
      }
      if (widget.label31 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label31);
      }
      if (widget.label32 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label32);
      }
      if (widget.label33 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label33);
      }
      if (widget.label34 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label34);
      }
      if (widget.label35 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label35);
      }
      if (widget.label36 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label36);
      }
      if (widget.label37 != '') {
        results.add(widget.label37);
      }
    
   
  
  
  
    
    
    }


  speak() {
    tts.setVolume(volume);
    tts.setRate(rate);
    // if (languageCode != null) {
    //   tts.setLanguage(languageCode!);
    // }
    tts.setPitch(pitch);
    tts.speak(results[**i**]);
```

Comment: If you want to use a local variable (in your case, `i`) in another function, you need to pass it as an argument to that function.

Comment: How do i do that ... please example

Comment: I think you need to follow some tutorials for the basics of software development. Because it's clear you don't even know how a for-loop works. You're doing it all wrong

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like the below, you can change the type, according to the `labels`/`results` type

```dart
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  var labels = ['1', '2', '3'];
  MyWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyWidget> createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  var results = <String>[];

  @override
  void initState() {
    savedata();
    super.initState();

    results = [];

    for (int i = 0; i < widget.labels.length; i++) {
      var label = widget.labels[i];
      if (label != '') {
        results.add(label);
         speak(label);
        // tts.setVolume(1.0);
      }
    }


    speak(String label) {
      ...
      tts.speak(label);
    }
  }

}
```